# RD Gateway and Web Application Proxy and AD FS

Tags: windows-server-2019, remote-desktop-services, rds, remote-desktop-gateway, web-application-proxy

I am trying to deploy an RD Gateway in combination with WAP (Web Application Proxy) and AD FS pre-authentication as described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210306182621/https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33630.adfs-wap-how-to-configure-sso-with-rdweb.aspx).

For a "proof of concept", I've decided to deploy all RDS roles to one server. Simplified, my environment now looks something like this:

[image: setup overview]

Where the server labeled "RDS" contains these roles:

- RD Web Access
- RD Gateway
- RD Licensing
- RD Connection Broker
- RD Virtualization Host

On the AD FS Farm, I configured the following Relying Part Trust, which only has the identifier set:

[image: relying party trust]

And on the WAP, the published application looks like this:

[image: wap application configuration]

Now, Internally everything works. A client in DEVPROD can access RD Web and connect to the vdi resources. 
On the WAP, everything works. On any server of the farm, I can access RD Web and connect to the vdi resources. 
From outside, I can access RD Web, but connections to the RD Gateway fail with this error message: 
[image: error message] 
On some clients, I also get:

> Your computer can't connect to the remote computer because the Remote Desktop Gateway server is temporarily unavailable.

What I've tried/checked

- All certs used are trusted and rdweb uses the correct one
- IIS does not have unused bindings
- Using windows authentication for IIS
- Setting pre-authentication to required in the custom rdp properties of the collection
- Setting DefaultTSGateway and radcmserver in the IIS application settings

Where would you start diagnosing this issue?